# How can i have tilemaps, in Unity version 5.6.7?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Well, because of my computers performance I decided to switch to Unity 5.6.7 but i cant create tile maps in my 2d game. I tried to create one, but in Create 2d Object menu its just sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Tilemap`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/class-Tilemap.html) was added in [Unity 2017.4](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/class-Tilemap.html).

In earlier versions it doesn't exist.

[image]

=> If you want to use it you'll have to at least use Unity `2017.4` or newer.